# Pymongo, best way to receive UNIQUE values inside a document's object

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm not sure if I'm using pymongo and mongodb the right way. I have a collection with 4000 documents, and each document are like this:

```
    {
  "_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "users": {
    "1": "Jones Doe",
    "2": "Foo Bar",
    "3": "Jonny Doe",
    "4": "Jones Bar",
    "5": "Foo Jones",    
  },
  "filename": "some_name_2011.csv",
  "racedate": "2011.05.24 10:33 PM GMT",
  "timestamp": 1306287180
}
```

So, I want to retrieve all the UNIQUE NAMES (no duplicates) that appear in "users" around all the collection. I have been reading some documentation about .find() and .distinct(), and the usage of both, but I couldnt perceive how could both functions give what I want. I think I should change how the data are configured in the JSON, but I wanted to listen thirds positioning about it.(Im using python 3)

[edit]

to make it clear, the order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc) **is important** for my app, that's why the 'users' object is like this.

Comment: What is your expected json output ? Can you change the users embedded document with named pairs to embedded array with key value pairs ? Something like `"users": [{"position":1, Name: "Jones Doe"},{"position":2....]` . Its possible without the schema modification but will not help you in the future queries and updates.

Comment: With schema modification it is pretty straightforward query `db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$users"},
  { "$sort": { "users.position": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
  "_id": "$users.position",
  "names": {"$addToSet:"$users.name"}
  }}
])`. Without  schema modification it involves an extra stage to transform to array structure `db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {"users:{"$objectToArray":"$users}},
  {"$unwind": "$users"},
  { "$sort": { "users.k": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
  "_id": "$users.k",
  "names": {"$addToSet:"$users.v"}
  }}
])`. All queries are 3.4 shell based.

Comment: What Im looking for is a simple array with all unique names. I actually have written a code to add the CSV files to mongodb, so it's totally fine for me to change it to something like you suggested. Do you think it would be a better and easier way to do it? @Veeram

Comment: Yes it is how the arrays are modeled in mongodb with key value pairs. Both the above queries outputs the unique names array for each position. Something like `[{"1":[bunch of unique names], "2":...}]`

Comment: @RamonBarros do you require the result to be ordered, or group by their position ? if not, you can use : `db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{"users":{$objectToArray:"$users"}}}, {$unwind:"$users"}, {$group:{_id:"$users.v"}}]`.